# Calculate values of resistors

Tags: transistors, resistors, voltage-divider

How to calculate values of R1, R2 and R3?

R4 is a load 40 Ohms 300 mA.

R3 is connected to ATMega8 output.
hFE3 of DB136 and BD135 is 40

[image]

Comment: http://www.regentsprep.org/Regents/physics/phys03/bkirchof2/

Comment: The question is impossible to answer without a spec what the circuit is supposed to do.  Also the text says R4 is 40 Ohms, but the schematic says 4 Ohms.  Make up your mind.

Comment: Circuit is supposed to drive 6 groups of 2 LEDs connected in series(like in LED strip). http://postimg.org/image/8w2jffxhp/

Comment: I fixed your schematic so it now shows the proper value for R4, so how about if you tell us whether the ATMega is putting out 3.3V or 5V?

Comment: @OlinLathrop: 1.) For the exercise of determining the values of R1, R2, and R3, the purpose of the circuit is irrelevant, given that the OP has made the load resistive. 2.)Since the text clearly states that the load current is 300 mA, it should be readily apparent that with a 12 volt supply driving the load and 300 mA through it, the 4 ohms given on the original schematic was an error.  Even more so since the text gave the obvious 40 ohms as the correct value.

Comment: There's an error in either the value you gave for R4 or in the values of the resistors in the circuit at the link you gave, in that even removing all the LEDs and paralleling all the resistors will yield a total resistance of 55 ohms. Putting in all the LEDs can only increase that resistance, so where's the error? BTW, do you have a link to the LED data sheet?

Answer (score 2):

It's accepted engineering practice - in switching circuits - to force transistors' betas to 10, so with that in mind, if Q2's collector current is 300 mA, then its base current should be set at 30 mA.

Q1's collector current would then be 30mA plus whatever came from R1, say 1mA, for a total of 31 mA.

The ATMega would then have to force 3.1 mA into Q1's base in order to turn ON Q2 and allow current into R4.

There are collector saturation voltages and base-to-emitter voltage drops to consider, and if the ATMegas's output was 3.3V, R3 would have to be changed in order to keep Q1's beta at 10. The schematic below assumes 5V out of the ATMega, and with the currents and voltages shown, should allow the resistances shown to be calculated using only Ohm's law.

There's an inconsistency or two because of liberties taken with Vbe(sat) and Vce(sat), and for confirmation, [here's the LTspice file](https://www.dropbox.com/s/yhw77fur83xbht7/Forced%20betas.asc?dl=0) you can run to simulate the circuit.

[image]

Comment: Though it makes no difference to the calculations, in that diagram there would be 34mA (not 33) flowing from the emitter of Q1 to GND - There is 3mA flowing into the base and 31mA into the collector.

Comment: @TomCarpenter 34 = = =  33 -> This is Engineering [tm] :-)